# Vim is loading the system syntax after my custom syntax so my custom syntax is not being applied

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I have a [custom](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1491) javascript syntax file in my ~/.vim/syntax folder on ubuntu 12.04, but when I open a .js file in vim is uses the system syntax instead:

Output of :scriptnames

```
  1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim73/debian.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syntax.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/synload.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syncolor.vim
  6: ~/.vim/filetype.vim
  7: /usr/share/vim/vim73/filetype.vim
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/gzip.vim
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/matchparen.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/spellfile.vim
 14: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/tohtml.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 18: ~/.vim/syntax/javascript.vim
 19: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/javascript.vim
```

How do I get my custom syntax to apply to *.js files?

Comment: What makes you believe that the custom syntax isn't being set properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the syntax file placed in the proper place which is `~/.vim/syntax/javascript.vim`. The reason the system syntax file shows up it that its was sourced. However the first couple of lines in the file check to see if some other syntax file was sourced. Since a current syntax is already set, the system syntax file exits without doing anything.

So the custom one is sourced first (and has all its highlighting applied). Then the system one sourced. This is why you see both in the output of `:scriptnames`

So to get vim to apply the custom syntax rules you need to do nothing because all the files are in the right place.

Comment: you're right. both syntax's use nearly the exact same color scheme, so I thought it wasn't working

Answer (score 1):

In my `.../vim73/syntax/javascript.vim`, I see the following code at the beginning:

```
if !exists("main_syntax")
  if version < 600
    syntax clear
  elseif exists("b:current_syntax")
    finish
  endif
  let main_syntax = 'javascript'
endif
```

and at the end:

```
let b:current_syntax = "javascript"
if main_syntax == 'javascript'
  unlet main_syntax
endif
```

I would suggest adding `let b:current_syntax = "javascript"` to the end of your custom syntax file. In fact, I that check `exists("b:current_syntax")` in a number of files in the syntax directory, so you probably should add a check at the beginning of yours too:

```
if exists("b:current_syntax")
    finish
endif
```

Comment: this is the custom syntax file that I'm using: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1491, and it has that. Do I need to restart my server or something to get it to take effect?

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to restart. Are you sure that your custom syntax isn't actually being used? You would still see it load the last one, even if all it did was finish immediately.Assuming you have root, I would try moving the last one out of the way to confirm that something different happens without it.